# Build a function capable to trim the string with complete word

Tags: php, html, wordpress, codeigniter

Any one can help me to build a PHP function that is capable to perform strip_tags with HTML tag exception and trim the text only by the end of a word.

**Explanation**

I have a string like this:

> `<p><a href="#">Click here</a> to change the picture in my website.<span>Powered</span><em> By <em> administrator</p>`

I just need a function that is capable to trim the content by limit. Suppose the limit what i given is end in the middle of a word, i need to trim perform only after the end of the word.

**Like this** i provide the trim limit as 10, may be the 10 is end in the middle of word **cha**, I need the felicity to trim must show my full word like **change**

Also need the option to strip the HTML tags from the string with exception optio.

Am using something like this

> `<?php
>       $string ='<p><a href="#">Click here</a> to change the picture in my website.<span>Powered</span><em> By <em> administrator</p>';
>       $string = strip_tags($string,'<p><a><span>');
>       $string = substr($string,0,35);
>   ?>`

But here i got the out like **Click here to ch** i need the out like **Click here to change**

**Any one can help me to build a function like this ??**

Comment: What did you tried? Show us the code...

Comment: Show the desired result

Comment: @machineaddict right now am using substr($content,0,100) is using for trim the string but that cutting my word without completing. So do have any other option to get the word full ??

Comment: Please edit your question and post that code you said inside it. And I would also like to see the answer to this question :).

Comment: _i need to trim perform only after the end of the word_ It would be more reasonable to cut text **before** the word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str='Thanks for submitting your request.';$part1 = substr($str,0,8);
$strword =explode(' ',str_replace($part1,'',$str));
echo $part1.$strword[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

CodeIgniter has a pretty good function that does just this:

```
/**


* Character Limiter
 *
 * Limits the string based on the character count.  Preserves complete words
 * so the character count may not be exactly as specified.
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @param   integer
 * @param   string  the end character. Usually an ellipsis
 * @return  string
 */
if ( ! function_exists('character_limiter'))
{
    function character_limiter($str, $n = 500, $end_char = '&#8230;')
    {
        if (strlen($str) < $n)
        {
            return $str;
        }

        $str = preg_replace("/\s+/", ' ', str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), ' ', $str));

        if (strlen($str) <= $n)
        {
            return $str;
        }

        $out = "";
        foreach (explode(' ', trim($str)) as $val)
        {
            $out .= $val.' ';

            if (strlen($out) >= $n)
            {
                $out = trim($out);
                return (strlen($out) == strlen($str)) ? $out : $out.$end_char;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The usage is pretty straightforward:

```
$string ='<p><a href="#">Click here</a> to change the picture in my website.<span>Powered</span><em> By <em> administrator</p>';
$string = strip_tags($string,'<p><a><span>');    
$string = character_limit($string, 35);
```

You can also modify the function to have another optional parameter for stripping html tags.